# Graph Line Parallel to X Axis in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I'm thinking this is extremely simple. I would like to graph the line y = 7.87.  This graphs a line parallel to the y-axis, but I'm looking for something horizontal, parallel with x-axis. Any ideas?

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    plt.axvline(x = 7.85)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Shouldn't it say 'x axis' in the title of your question?

Comment: You are absolutely right. My mistake.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It really is quite simple:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.axhline(y=7.87)

plt.show()
```

The `h` and `v` in the function names (`axhline` and `axvline`) stand for *horizontal* and *vertical*.